# Using VBA macro to SaveAs but keep original file open

Tags: excel, vba, file-format, save-as

I am using a macro that runs automatically when opening my file, which includes a "SaveAs" function. However, I would like the original file to stay open after saving in case I need to double check the data or want to make a change.
I have read that people suggest the use of the "SaveAsCopy" function, however, I need to save it as an .XLXS and not an .XLSM file, which "SaveAsCopy" doesn't seem to have the ability to do.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
Sub SaveWorkbook()

Dim wb, wbnew As Workbook
Dim FileName As String
Dim FilePath As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

FilePath = "C:\" 'Your File Path
FileName = "Saved File" 'Your File Name

wb.Activate

'Copies sheets to new workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
 
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show FilePath & FileName

'OR alternatively
'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & FileName & ".xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll have to try harder. After running your code, the `.xlsx` file stays open instead of the initial `.xlsm` file.

Comment: Sorry my fault!